# Writing a library that works for BitStrings or Lists

Tags: elixir

I'm working on a project that involves a lot of byte-level manipulation. I would like the library to accept binaries as input, but it's often convenient to work with functions on `Enum`. I've ended up with a lot of functions that have two guarded definitions, one for `when is_binary` and one for `when is_list`:

```elixir
@doc """
Convert a binary or list of bytes to a hexadecimal string representation,

## Examples

    iex> Bytes.to_hex <<1,2,3,253,254,255>>
    "010203fdfeff"

    iex> Bytes.to_hex [1,2,3,253,254,255]
    '010203fdfeff'
"""
def to_hex(bytes) when is_binary(bytes) do
  :binary.bin_to_list(bytes) |> to_hex |> :binary.list_to_bin
end

def to_hex(bytes) when is_list(bytes) do
  hexes = Enum.map bytes, &byte_to_hex/1
  Enum.join(hexes) |> String.downcase |> :binary.bin_to_list
end

defp byte_to_hex(byte) do
  Integer.to_char_list(byte, 16) |> :string.right(2, ?0)
end
```

In addition, there's the `:binary.bin_to_list` at the end of the list version followed by the `:binary.list_to_bin` at the end of the string version, resulting in superfluous work.

I'd really like to be able to use the same abstractions for binaries, as well. I initially tried doing this by implementing a protocol for `BitString`:

```elixir
defimpl Enumerable, for: BitString do
  def count(coll) do
    {:ok, byte_size(coll)}
  end

  def member?(_coll, _val) do
    {:error, __MODULE__}
  end

  def reduce(_, {:halt, acc}, _fun) do
    {:halted, acc}
  end

  def reduce(bin, {:suspend, acc}, fun) do
    {:suspended, acc, &reduce(bin, &1, fun)}
  end

  def reduce(<<>>, {:cont, acc}, _fun) do
    {:done, acc}
  end

  def reduce(<< h :: binary-size(1), t :: binary >>, {:cont, acc}, fun) do
    reduce(t, fun.(h, acc), fun)
  end
end
```

This works great for the `count`, `member`, and `reduce` cases:

```elixir
test "counts bytes" do
  assert Enum.count(<<0, 1, 2>>) == 3
end

test "reports members" do
  assert Enum.member?(<<0, 1, 2>>, <<3>>) == false
  assert Enum.member?(<<0, 1, 2>>, <<2>>) == true
end

test "reduces binaries" do
  reducer = fn(b, acc) -> b <> acc end
  assert Enum.reduce("abc", "", reducer) == "cba"
end
```

However, some `Enum` functions call out to functions on `:lists`; for example, `Enum.map` calls `:lists.reverse`, so this gives different output:

```elixir
test "maps binaries" do
  mapper = fn(<<b>>) -> <<b + 1>> end
  assert Enum.map(<<0, 1, 2 >>, mapper) == <<1, 2, 3>>
end
```

```
1) test maps binaries
   Assertion with == failed
   code: Enum.map(<<0, 1, 2>>, mapper) == <<1, 2, 3>>
   lhs:  [<<1>>, <<2>>, <<3>>]
   rhs:  <<1, 2, 3>>
```

What is the most idiomatic way to deal with this kind of situation? Should I simply keep with the guards and implement the list <-> binary conversions? Should I create a specific module for the functions, like `List` is to `Enum`?

**Edit**

I thought I could take care of the extra list <-> binary conversions by making the binary the base case:

```elixir
def to_hex(bytes) when is_binary(bytes) do
  bytes
  |> :binary.bin_to_list
  |> Enum.map(&byte_to_hex/1)
  |> Enum.join
end

def to_hex(bytes) when is_list(bytes) do
  bytes |> :binary.list_to_bin |> to_hex |> :binary.bin_to_list
end

defp byte_to_hex(byte) do
  Integer.to_string(byte, 16) |> String.rjust(2, ?0) |> String.downcase
end
```

But of course, there's still the same number of `list_to_bin` and `bin_to_list` calls in this version, just moved around. Is there just no way around this?

Comment: Did you publish you lib?

Comment: @Sheharyar I was working on the Matasano Crypto Challenges. The code is old but is here: https://github.com/BinaryMuse/matasano-crypto-challenges/tree/master/elixir

Answer (score 0):

It looks weird that you get binaries whil enumerating a binary. To me, they should be integers. Just like a char list.

Then functions like `Enum.map` would work as expected.